# Cannot rewind or go forward after initially seek the video?

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer, seekbar, seek

I am seek the video before it starts play. That is working fine. All videos starts play after the seek time given and playing. That is really fine.

But I cannot rewind or forward the video after that. Because if I forward or rewind video starts to play from the started seek position. Assume my seek position is from 5 minutes and I am forwarding when I am in 10th minute, the video starts again from 5 minute where my seek starts.

How can I solve this please ? This is my current code.

```
jwplayer('myPlayer').setup({
    file: video_url_here,
    image: video_poster_here,
    title: 'Play',
    width: '800',
    height: '500',
    skin: 'glow',
    autostart: 'true',
    primary: 'flash'
});

if(resume_time > 0) {
    jwplayer('myPlayer').onPlay(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        jwplayer('myPlayer').seek(resume_time);
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Basically, whenever your code is executed, it skips **to 5 minutes**.

### Solution

You need to skip **by 5 minutes**.

1. First get current position:

   - **JWPlayer API:** `jwp.getPosition()`
   - HTML5 Video Web API: `jwp.currentTime`
2. Next, add the offset time to the current position:

   - **JWPlayer API:** `jwp.getPosition() + offset`

The following demo is using the JWPlayer API:

1. **.getPosition()**
2. **.seek()**
3. **.addButton()**

As does your original code, it starts at an offset. The test video is only a minute long so all time offsets are in seconds.

1. Type or scroll 0-60 seconds
2. Click the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button located in the top right corner
3. Note that the video will advance the number of seconds entered in box **from the current position**. So if <kbd>Skip</kbd> was clicked with 19.5 in the input and the player is at 26, the player should advance to 45.5.

### Demo

```js
var jwp = jwplayer('botr_xJ7Wcodt_5QOesuLn_div');

jwp.setup({
  file: '//clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
  title: 'Test Time Offset',
  width: '320',
  height: '180',
  skin: 'glow',
  key: "0H8QSBHQ3gTepr3hHusMAITnanKbD/JxzJYAKaDkZ5zwOSkLOgBqew=="
});

var offset = 5;

jwp.on('ready', function(event) {
  var now = jwp.getPosition();
  var goTo = offset + now;
  jwp.seek(goTo);
});

jwp.addButton(
  'https://www.mix96.co.uk/shared/images/sky-news-play-24.png',
  'Skip',
  function() {
    jwp.seek(
      jwp.getPosition() + (parseFloat(document.forms[0].elements[0].value)));
  },
  'skip'
);
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  outline: 3px inset blue;
  width: 5ch;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0
}
```

```html
<script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/xJ7Wcodt-5QOesuLn.js"></script>


<div id='botr_xJ7Wcodt_5QOesuLn_div'></div>

<form>
  <input type='number' min='0' max='60' step='1.5'> Seconds
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set one variable flag on click of `forward` or `rewind` and check that same condition while seek through `onPlay`.

```
var isRewindOrForward = false; // Initial load

// logic for forward and rewind here and reset isRewindOrForward to false again

if(resume_time > 0) {
jwplayer('myPlayer').onPlay(function() {
  if(!isRewindOrForward){
      setTimeout(function() {
      jwplayer('myPlayer').seek(resume_time);
      }, 500);
     }
  });
}
```